# Is it possible to enable google pubsub push directly to an API Gateway endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, api-gateway

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding aspects of this, but the scenario is this:

I have a collection of services in which some endpoints should be publicly accessible, and others should only be accessible to service accounts associated with cloud functions or services. I am considering using API Gateway to deal with this, instead of duplicating services.

I understand how to set up security for API Gateway, to allow most endpoints to be public, but have a security requirement for certain endpoints restricted to specific service accounts.

However I have found that service to service communication between services and api gateway is different than communication between, for example, two cloud run services, in that you sign a JWT rather than using the google client libraries or metadata server to get an ID token.

My understanding is that when creating a pubsub/scheduler task and connecting it to a cloud run service, it is sending an ID token of a service account listed as an invoker for that service. So my question is, how could I schedule a recurring call to a secured api gateway endpoint, when that expects a signed jwt? The only solution I could think of would be having the pubsub service account invoke a function that then signs the JWT and relays the request to API gateway, which I think is too complicated to be practical. Using API keys seems like a step down in terms of security, so I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: If you request a JWT signed by Google, you can set up a OIDC security configuration. Did you investigate this way? If so, what's your current issue?